# What is the production connection between Tomorrowland and Stargate?

Tags: stargate, tomorrowland

I'm assuming there is one because Tomorrowland has the following three Stargate actors:

[David Nykl](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0638706/)(SGA-- Dr. Zalenka),

[Paul McGillion](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0569295/) (SGA-- Dr. Beckett),

and [Garry Chalk](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0149942/) (SG1-- Colonel Chekov).

Perhaps it is just that they are all filmed in the Vancouver area, but the coincidence seems bigger.

Comment: Huh. I didn't even notice that. Didn't recognize any of those three in Tomorrowland when I saw it. And I'm a big SG fan.

Comment: i mean its been what 5+ years since the end of stargate, and these are like b/c/d tier cast members....

Comment: Yeah you might be clutching at straws here. If it was Jack, Sam and Teal'c, maybe there could be a connection but these three are right down the list.

Comment: I noticed them, too, and thought "HEY! SG Easter Egg!" But that was about it.

Comment: it's very common to see genre actors reappear in future genre shows, especially when they're filmed in the same area. AFAIK all three of those actors live in the Vancouver area.

Comment: @BBlake:  I didn't notice David Nykl until I looked up the cast on imdb, but I think he had facial hair and no accent.

Answer (score 11):

Comparing *Tomorrowland* and *Stargate: Atlantis* gets quite a [long list](http://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt1964418,tt0374455) of cast and crew the two have in common.  However, since you're asking about shared actors, let's look at casting.

[Corrine Clark](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0163790/) and [Jennifer Page](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0656206/) are listed as the Casting Director on *Tomorrowland*, and back in 2008-2009 they worked on *Stargate: Atlantis* and in 2009-2011 they worked on *Stargate: Universe*.  So they're your likely suspects for why a handful of *Stargate* actors ended up acting in *Tomorrowland*.

Comment: I miss SGA & SGU :(